# Dynamically added javascript not running

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a website that is heavily built on ajax. Some of my JS comes as part of the pages that I load through ajax. The functions from the JS cannot be called from other JS scripts that has been loaded earlier. As I have understand it, it has to with the code not being really declared and that I could use `eval()` on the code. But that feels like waste of resources since the code runs and works aslong it don't need to work with code that is already declared.

My little short ajax page loader.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var old = "home"
    $("#topMenu a").on("click",function(){
        if(typeof edit_menu !== 'undefined' && edit_menu){
            return;
        }
        var link = $(this).attr("data-link");
        //Load Ajax
        LoadPage(link, old);
    });
});

function LoadPage(link, old){
    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/" + link + ".php",
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
    Hide();
    history.pushState(old,null,"?page=" + link);
}
```

If I login as admin I will then also have an admin JS file loaded as part of the DOM. The script calls a function in another JS file thats is loaded dynamically. The function doesn't run because the admin JS file is not aware of the new funciton.

The dynamically added JS file is a script tag part of other HTML code.
Example of dynamically added code.

```
    <script src="/javascript/projects.js"></script>
    <header>Projects</header>

<article>
    <h1>First project</h1>
    <section class="summary">
Lorem ipsum is da shit
    </section>
    <section class="text">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed diam orci, hendrerit a justo sit amet, egestas ullamcorper orci. Aliquam quis facilisis urna. Fusce blandit pellentesque elit. Vivamus ullamcorper luctus felis in rutrum. Nam quis facilisis mauris. Nunc iaculis sagittis sollicitudin. Ut imperdiet, purus et fermentum tempor, leo mauris feugiat libero, eu pulvinar odio felis sed tortor. Mauris vel libero orci. Suspendisse a mollis turpis. Maecenas egestas felis eget ultrices porta. Nulla non metus ut augue faucibus ultrices. Phasellus arcu magna, vulputate eget sollicitudin a, ullamcorper a ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget vulputate ipsum.</p>             <p>Ut ultricies faucibus sapien, ut sodales turpis rhoncus molestie. Vivamus luctus auctor pellentesque. Phasellus ut ex vulputate, congue felis nec, pharetra odio. Ut ligula ante, luctus nec enim ac, lobortis ultrices elit. Quisque sed justo a nibh congue tempor sit amet ut mauris. In non enim nulla. Nulla et dolor sollicitudin, finibus ante eu, egestas purus. Phasellus sit amet eros dignissim, pellentesque elit tempor, sagittis eros. Donec sollicitudin velit ipsum, semper ultrices sapien blandit non. Phasellus vehicula orci in ipsum blandit hendrerit. Vestibulum facilisis dolor ac tincidunt fermentum.</p>
    </section>
    <span>Update text</span> <input type="checkbox" class="update_projects" data-id="First project" /><br /><button class="update_text">Update</button><input type="hidden" class="token" value="4926dd431992894a8364ca4d89733038be0cb0ec4897eb2a417637685554b6df40149522a858b5bfaaa91526b84718cdd54b301229371841dc2f022bbd0f804eaf31abb51caef55b26cca3209cc3b0838f194176f78f0931b2217669cd2912faa25a3c3e469ce686d79ac7a7852fbfee9d6d4dc5da18b499e703b4ef57fc88c1a99ccf8943af5853433f911ce276ff13e9ecbfb074d747f1a07f26c141f80383a149902dfe7469262724e2f67aae48d9919d486855a892b17681660ab3e0d25f98e714c3d98cc903" /><input type="hidden" class="id" value="1" /><br /><input type="text" name="tag" class="tag" value="php" />
</article><article>
    <h1>Secons project</h1>
    <section class="summary">
And I'm not lying
    </section>
    <section class="text">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed diam orci, hendrerit a justo sit amet, egestas ullamcorper orci. Aliquam quis facilisis urna. Fusce blandit pellentesque elit. Vivamus ullamcorper luctus felis in rutrum. Nam quis facilisis mauris. Nunc iaculis sagittis sollicitudin. Ut imperdiet, purus et fermentum tempor, leo mauris feugiat libero, eu pulvinar odio felis sed tortor. Mauris vel libero orci. Suspendisse a mollis turpis. Maecenas egestas felis eget ultrices porta. Nulla non metus ut augue faucibus ultrices. Phasellus arcu magna, vulputate eget sollicitudin a, ullamcorper a ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eget vulputate ipsum.</p>
            <p>Ut ultricies faucibus sapien, ut sodales turpis rhoncus molestie. Vivamus luctus auctor pellentesque. Phasellus ut ex vulputate, congue felis nec, pharetra odio. Ut ligula ante, luctus nec enim ac, lobortis ultrices elit. Quisque sed justo a nibh congue tempor sit amet ut mauris. In non enim nulla. Nulla et dolor sollicitudin, finibus ante eu, egestas purus. Phasellus sit amet eros dignissim, pellentesque elit tempor, sagittis eros. Donec sollicitudin velit ipsum, semper ultrices sapien blandit non. Phasellus vehicula orci in ipsum blandit hendrerit. Vestibulum facilisis dolor ac tincidunt fermentum.</p>
    </section>
    <span>Update text</span> <input type="checkbox" class="update_projects" data-id="Secons project" /><br /><button class="update_text">Update</button><input type="hidden" class="token" value="4926dd431992894a8364ca4d89733038be0cb0ec4897eb2a417637685554b6df40149522a858b5bfaaa91526b84718cdd54b301229371841dc2f022bbd0f804eaf31abb51caef55b26cca3209cc3b0838f194176f78f0931b2217669cd2912faa25a3c3e469ce686d79ac7a7852fbfee9d6d4dc5da18b499e703b4ef57fc88c1a99ccf8943af5853433f911ce276ff13e9ecbfb074d747f1a07f26c141f80383a149902dfe7469262724e2f67aae48d9919d486855a892b17681660ab3e0d25f98e714c3d98cc903" /><input type="hidden" class="id" value="2" /><br /><input type="text" name="tag" class="tag" value="" />
</article></section>
```

**UPDATE**
After some more testing I have found the JS can't find any of my added HTML while the js added on the same time can.

Comment: Where are you adding in the admin scripts? How are you using them?

Comment: @JesseFarmer When I login, a new fresh page is requested and the admin.js in the head the site.

Comment: I wish I could see more. The scripting. The function calls. What you are trying to do should work. You have JavaScript in admin.js that is not getting called from AJAX injected HTML, right? There is something else...

Comment: the admin.js is trying to call a function in the loaded js. I can also add from some more testing that the admin.js can't find any HTML that is added.

Comment: How are you calling the function/s in admin.js on the AJAX-added content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script, this will remove the script from the loaded HTML and load them on to the page before adding the content. Also it makes sure that the same javascript file does not get added multiple times.

```
function LoadPage(link, old){
    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/" + link + ".php",
    }).done(function(data){
        $loadedData = $("<div>"+data+"</div>");
        $loadedData.find('script[src]').each(function(i,v){
            var jsPath = $(this).attr('src');
            if($('[src="'+jsPath+'"]').length == 0){
               var tag = document.createElement('script');
               tag.src = jsPath;
               var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
               firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            }
        });
        $loadedData.find('script[src]').remove(); 
        $("#content").html($loadedData.html());
    });
    Hide();
    history.pushState(old,null,"?page=" + link);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked witht the combination that I had to change all on functions `$(".class").on("click", function(){})` to `$("body").on("click", ".class", function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

I am trying *to understand the question* but as i can't comment for the moment some parts of it are not enugh clear, i work with *jsfiddle* if it can help, is it possible to make a *little example* not all the code to help me understand what's going on. Starting with 
this function for example :

```
function LoadPage(link, old){
    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/" + link + ".php",
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
    Hide();
    history.pushState(old,null,"?page=" + link);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3z62n8c2/

Comment: The is called when a link in the menu is clicked.

$.ajax part loads the new page.

history.pushState changes the url.

Hide(); Is function that hides a message box on the website.

Comment: This code works though, ya? I mean, you'er getting the HTML, but the functions in the new (from AJAX) html is coming back 'undefined' for for calls to functions in 'admin.js'. Is that right?

Comment: The admin.js code works fine exept it can't find any code that is added through ajax.

Comment: You mean there is no `<script>` tag in the document but your script is runned well ?

Comment: Yes it's is a script tag, but the admin.js code can't find the function in the new file loaded by the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

To load the script you must append it as an HTML element, like this :

```
}).done(function(data) {
    var el = $(document.createElement('div')).html(data);
    var scripts = el.find('script');

    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        window.eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
        scripts[i].remove();
    }

    $('#content').html(el.html());
});
```

Comment: Really ? I will edit my answer, run the code again after editing

Comment: Well, not working either. Got this error.

`TypeError: scripts[i].html is not a function
 

window.eval(scripts[i].html());`

Comment: Nope, not even the code that should run directly on load runs now.

Comment: Your script is runned well or not at all ?

Comment: With your code, the browser laods the JS file but doesn't evaluate it.

Comment: How do you know the JS file is loaded ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116278/discussion-between-clementnerma-and-olof).